# How can I incorporate an input limit of 999 in my calculator script?

Tags: python-3.3

I am aware this is a duplicate from a past thread, but when I use that suggestion, it says 'unindent does not match any outer indentation level'. When I run the script at school (this is a school assignment) a blank GUI appears with no buttons, and when I run it at home, it appears with the error message as above- I am using Python 3.3.2 on each computer. The code for the 999 limit is in lines 45-57 and the error message appears on the first line (45). I'm quite new to python and my teacher is awful, so apologies if my question sounds quite silly. Can I have a suggestion as to how to get this to work?
Thanks a lot!

```
from tkinter import *

class Calculator(Frame):

    def frame(this, side): 
        w = Frame(this)
        w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        return w


    def button(this, root, side, text, command=None): 
        w = Button(root, text=text, command=command) 
        w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        return w    

    need_clr = False
    def digit(self, digit):
        if self.need_clr:
            self.display.set('')
            self.need_clr = False
        self.display.set(self.display.get() + digit)

    def sign(self):
        need_clr = False
        cont = self.display.get()
        if len(cont) > 0 and cont[0] == '-':
            self.display.set(cont[1:])
        else:
            self.display.set('-' + cont)


    def oper(self, op):
        self.display.set(self.display.get() + ' ' + op + ' ')
        self.need_clr = False

    def calc(self):
        try:
            self.display.set(eval(self.display.get()))
            self.need_clr = True
        except:
            showerror('Operation Error', 'Illegal Operation')
            self.display.set('')
            self.need_clr = False

   def calc(self):
       try:
           self.display.set(self.validate_result(eval(self.display.get())))
           self.need_clr = True
           except:
               showerror('Operation Error', 'Illegal Operation')
               self.display.set('')
               self.need_clr = False
               def validate_result(self, result):
                   if result >= 1000:
                       raise ValueError('result too big!')
                    else:
                        return result

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Dotum 15')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Simple Calculator')

        self.display = StringVar()
        e = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, textvariable=self.display)
        e.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        for key in ("123", "456", "789"):
            keyF = self.frame(TOP)
            for char in key:
                self.button(keyF, LEFT, char,
                            lambda c=char: self.digit(c))

        keyF = self.frame(TOP)
        self.button(keyF, LEFT, '0', lambda ch='0': self.digit(ch))

        opsF = self.frame(TOP)
        for char in "+-=":
            if char == '=':
                btn = self.button(opsF, LEFT, char, self.calc)
            else:
                btn = self.button(opsF, LEFT, char, 
                                  lambda w=self, s=char: w.oper(s))

        clearF = self.frame(BOTTOM)
        self.button(clearF, LEFT, 'Clr', lambda w=self.display: w.set(''))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Calculator().mainloop()
```

Comment: I know next-to-nothing about Python, but doesn't the error message tell you that the indentation is wrong? Look at the `try:` `except:` indendation in, say, [wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) and compare it to what you have. **Edit** You should have given a link to what you suggest is the prior question.

Comment: A silly question is not a problem; a _bad_ question is. And a _bad_ question is one that is hard to answer and/or not useful to others. Your question has way too much unrelated code. Please try and cut it down to the shortest reproducible example demonstrating the problem. Also, Andrew is right and `except` is indented incorrectly. Another side note: if input validation is not your actual problem anymore, you might want to give your question a more descriptive title.